# applications that would benefit having a 64bit Os on a 64bit cpu with maximum of 4gb ram

Tags: cpu

I am trying to find out for which kind of applications (cpu intensive, io intensive, good mix of cpu/io apps) it is worth putting a 64 bit Os on 64 bit hardware instead of a 32 bit os where the Ram cannot be extended more than 4GB?

Comment: Depends, if you are using this to run a web browser and check our mail, not much. If you are running any heavy duty calculations then enormously. I recommend reading up on what 64bit computing is good for (hint it can be extremely useful even if you only have 500MB of RAM) and asking again, this is way to general to be answerable as it stands.

Comment: I've made an edit and had to make some assumptions. please let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: Depends what you do. My first amd64 machine had 2GB RAM. My first 64-bit machine had a lot less, I've forgotten because it was a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; On Intel/AMD CPUs you are just about as fast in 32 bit mode as in 64 bit mode.

---

As for a somewhat more detailed answer:

It depends on a lot of things:

Qua non-performance: You will get access to a much larger address space. This is a good thing.

This address space is used for a lot of things, including:

- Mapping IO devices (e.g. your graphical cards buffer, which already can be up to 6 GiB)
- Physical memory (which causes the max 4GiB RAM limit, assuming no PEA)
- For virtual memory (please map programs semi randomly to this for security. So leave a few GB free. In other words, if you have 32 bit and some PCI[e] space then please do not use more then 512MiB for both RAM and IO, so that you remain with enough address space for map programs in and to keep this semi-random for security). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR as a nice starting point on address space layout randomization.

Qua performance:

- 64 bit code uses pointers which are twice the size of 32 bit points. This makes the programs larger and you end up with less memory for other tasks such as buffers.
- Larger programs need more cache, or you get reduced cache efficiency.

On AMD or Intel CPU's only:

- In amd64 mode you get twice the number of registers than in 32 bit mode. Since the x86 architecture has a relative low number of registers you needed a lot of memory access, which is a bad thing. If your program is not memory bound then this can speed things up by a rather significant amount.
- Amd64 (that is both Intel and AMD CPU's in 64 bit mode, not to be confused with Intels [IA64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) bit mode which is quite different) only support the [no-execute bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) in their page tables if you run in 64 bit mode. Security wise you also want this.

Having said that, for your **average* program and on amd64: there is no speed change. Advantages and disadvantages seem equally large and cancel each other out.  This is not true on other architectures such as power PC 64 which come with sufficient registers in both 32 and 64 bit versions of the chip.

Finally, for practical reasons:

- Always use the 64 bit version if you think you might expand the memory beyond 4 GiB.
- If you have multiple OS installation try to keep the same version in use on all of them to keep things simple. (Which these days means use the 64 bit version on all of them).
- And for security use it on all nodes with 512MiB+ RAM if you use an OS with address space randomisation. (Read: for any modern OS).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is unless you are constantly pushing every bit of your 4gb of RAM, 32bit will normally get the same performance vs 64bit. In fact, most 32bit applications have a smaller memory footprint so there will be times when 32bit will preform better than 64bit. After 4gb of RAM, 64bit is astronomically better than 32bit, but until then you can go either way and not see much of a performance difference.